# Why does an Android phone with Snapdragon 732G run slower than an Android phone with Snapdragon 678?

Tags: xiaomi, performance, redmi

I am comparing the two phones:

```
Xiaomi Poco X3 NFC - Snapdragon 732G (8 nm) - Adreno 618 - Android 10, MIUI 12
Redmi Note 10 - Snapdragon 678 (11 nm) - Adreno 612 - Android 11, MIUI 12
```

For both of them, if I dual open Pokemon Go using MIUI's dual app, Redmi Note 10 has smooth graphics on both apps, while Xiaomi Poco X3 NFC is more like 15 frames per second: the graphics is quite lagging.

It was quite strange that I checked the specs of their CPU and GPU, only to find that Poco X3 is supposedly at least 50% faster than Redmi Note 10. The only difference is that Poco X3 is  Android 10, while Redmi Note 10 is Android 11.

What is the reason for such drastic difference: a slower CPU and GPU but faster? Is it just due to Android 10 vs 11?  It seems Poco X3 won't update Android officially but I have to rely on some 3rd party installation.

Comment: is it real benchmark or just a feeling? both phones are running on same storage fill level, same google play services version, same internet speed, same amount of pokemon cache files, same list of installed apps, and running same amount of background processes at time of benchmark? if you can eliminate all kind of side effects and ensure that the *"only difference"* is android version, yes then it probably is related to android version and/or updates

Comment: Yes, the Poco X3 NFC recently came out with an Android 11 update, and after that, both phones run at similar speed, so it seems Android 10 and 11 made a difference. What might be unknown is why the Poco X3 NFC not noticeably faster then the Redmi Note 10. If I use the Xiaomi 11i, it is noticeable faster then the Redmi Note 10